# Checking if item is null or if a table doesn't contain any matching data

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got this query where I'm trying to check if there is an item in the table `TruckItems` that matches the string value in the variable `tareTotal`.

```
public QuoteResult GetTruckInformation(QuoteData data)
{
    QuoteResult qr = null;

    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var tareTotal = db.ChassisModel.Where(x => x.Id == data.ChassisId).FirstOrDefault();

        var items = (from x in db.TruckItems where x.Model == tareTotal.Name select x); //Issue lies here

        if (items.Any()) //Error here
        {
            var truckTareTotal = db.TruckItems.Where(x => x.Model == tareTotal.Name).FirstOrDefault().TareTotal;
            var truckGVM = db.TruckItems.Where(x => x.Model == tareTotal.Name).FirstOrDefault().GVM;

            var list = new QuoteResult
            {
                TareTotal = Convert.ToDouble(truckTareTotal),
                GVM = Convert.ToDouble(truckGVM)
            };
            qr = list;
        }
    }
    return qr;
}
```

I'm getting the error at `if (items.Any())`:

> Non-static method requires a target.

I do not fully understand my problem and I can't find anything that might help me with my problem. Can someone please give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong with my variable `items`? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everyone for helping me! All of your coding works perfectly fine. I've found my issue and for some reason it has something to do with threading...

In my client side application I used the `GetTruckInformation` method in a combobox selection changed event and for some reason when it runs through that event, my server side application changes threads between all my statements, thus resulting in all of my data being `null`.

Here is my WPF/client side method just for show:

```
private async void cmbChassisModel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (TruckServiceClient service = new TruckServiceClient())
    {
        QuoteData data = new QuoteData();
        data.ChassisId = cmbChassisModel.GetDisplayItemId();
        var items = await service.GetTruckInformationAsync(data);
        if (items != null)
        {
            lblTareTotalAmount.Content = items.TareTotal;
            lblGVMAmount.Content = items.GVM;
        }
    }
}
```

No one has to answer to this issue, I just wanted to let everyone know. :) I will try and figure out why this would happen. :)

Comment: probably `tareTotal` is `null`

Comment: @GeneR tareTotal is never null, as it gets it's values from another table that's values are seeded when the database is created.

Comment: Have you debugged it? And also have 3 queryes in row to same table with same condition, which is bad code

Comment: @CareTaker22 if no items match the `db.ChassisModel.Where(x => x.Id == data.ChassisId)` then `tareTotal` will be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `.ToList()` on the items. Like this:

```
var items= db.TruckItems.Where(w=>w.Model == tareTotal.Name).ToList();
```

Otherwise you might run into troubles when executing `.Any()`

**Edit:**

Just for the sake of the expirment. Do this:

```
if(tareTotal==null)
    throw new Exception("The tare total is null");
var items= db.TruckItems.Where(w=>w.Model == tareTotal.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! But i'm still getting the error _Non-static method requires a target._ with this line of yours: `var items= db.TruckItems.Where(w=>w.Model == tareTotal.Name).ToList();`

Comment: @CareTaker22 : And you are 100% sure that tareTotal is not null?

Comment: Thanks for the help dude! :) i've updated my original question if you want to view it.

Answer (score 1):

If no items match the `db.ChassisModel.Where(x => x.Id == data.ChassisId)` then `tareTotal` will be null.
Anyway, if you only want to check if db.TruckItems contains `tareTotal.Name` or not, use this. This also improve performance:
Change:

```
var items = (from x in db.TruckItems where x.Model == tareTotal.Name select x);
if (items.Any())
```

to:

```
if(db.TruckItems.Any(x => x.Model == tareTotal.Name))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still getting the error _Non-static method requires a target._ in the line `if(db.TruckItems.Any(x => x.Model == tareTotal.Name` 0_o

Comment: @CareTaker22 if no items match the `db.ChassisModel.Where(x => x.Id == data.ChassisId)` then `tareTotal` will be null

Comment: Thanks for the help man! I've posted an edit in my question that shows the issue that I had.

Answer (score 1):

Check this optimized method:

```
public QuoteResult GetTruckInformation(QuoteData data)
{
    QuoteResult qr = null;

    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        var tareTotal = db.ChassisModel.Where(x => x.Id == data.ChassisId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (tareTotal != null)
        {
            var item = db.TruckItems.Where(x => x.Model == tareTotal.Name).FirstOrDefault();

            if (item != null)
            {
                var list = new QuoteResult
                {
                    TareTotal = Convert.ToDouble(item.TareTotal),
                    GVM = Convert.ToDouble(item.GVM)
                };
                qr = list;
            }
        }
    }
    return qr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort man! Please view my edit in my original question. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
var hasItems = (from x in db.TruckItems where x.Model == tareTotal.Name select x).Any();
```

Will be tru if you have at least one item matching your condition.